# Issue loading data from csv file - Java

Tags: java, csv

As it stands I have a data set in the form of a .csv file which you can find [**here**](http://www.cwa.mdx.ac.uk/csd3939/coursework/cw2DataSet1.csv). Also there is some brief documentation on it which you can find [**here**](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/optdigits/optdigits.names). What I am attempting to do is to manipulate the data set so that I can work with some machine learning algorithms but as it stands I can't seem to print the outputted data to the console

**ImageMatrix.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class ImageMatrix {
    public static int[] data;
    public int classCode;
    public ImageMatrix(int[] data, int classCode) {
        assert data.length == 64;

    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Class Code: " + classCode + " DataSet:" + Arrays.toString(data) + "\n";
    }

    public int[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public int getClassCode() {
        return classCode;
    }

}
```

**ImageMatrixDB.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;




public class ImageMatrixDB implements Iterable<ImageMatrix> {
    List<ImageMatrix> list = new ArrayList<ImageMatrix>();

    public static ImageMatrixDB load(String f) throws IOException {
        ImageMatrixDB result = new ImageMatrixDB();
        try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
            for (String line; null != (line = br.readLine()); ) {
                int lastComma = line.lastIndexOf(',');
                int classCode = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(1 + lastComma));
                int[] data = Arrays.stream(line.substring(0, lastComma).split(","))
                                   .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                                   .toArray();
                result.list.add(new ImageMatrix(data, classCode));
            }
            System.out.println(ImageMatrix.data.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }



    public Iterator<ImageMatrix> iterator() {
        return this.list.iterator();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ImageMatrixDB i = new ImageMatrixDB();
        i.load("dataset1.csv"); // <<< ERROR IS HERE
    }
}
```

The error is within my main function on the line i.load(... I know I must be missing something or have made a mistake somewhere, I have tried altering the data from static but it just throws more errors and I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you create an ImageMatrixDB in main, then in your ImageMatrixDB.load() method create another instance of ImageMatrixDB?

Comment: What would you recommend, I see you point.

Comment: Well in the instance you create in main you call load on that instance. in the load method, just set the list on `this` instead of result and return `this` if you want (this would be the current instance). Also can you provide the ImageMatrix class?

Comment: Nevermind, I see the ImageMatrix class. On a side note, you should not make fields public like data in ImageMatrix. Make them private and provide public getter/setter methods.

Comment: What's the error msg?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Unhandled exception type IOException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in the `ImageMatrix` class.
You never set the `int[] data` in the constructor. You have:

```
    public ImageMatrix(int[] data, int classCode) {
        assert data.length == 64;

    }
```

You need:

```
    public ImageMatrix(int[] data, int classCode) {
        assert data.length == 64;
        this.data = data;
        this.classCode = classCode;
    }
```

Here is your updated/complete/working code:

ImageMatrix:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ImageMatrix {
    private int[] data;
    private int classCode;

public ImageMatrix(int[] data, int classCode) {
    assert data.length == 64;
    this.data = data;
    this.classCode = classCode;
}

    public String toString() {
        return "Class Code: " + classCode + " DataSet:" + Arrays.toString(data) + "\n";
    }

    public int[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public int getClassCode() {
        return classCode;
    }

}
```

ImageMatrixDB:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class ImageMatrixDB implements Iterable<ImageMatrix> {
        private List<ImageMatrix> list = new ArrayList<ImageMatrix>();

        public ImageMatrixDB load(String f) throws IOException {
            try (
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
                String line = null;

                while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    int lastComma = line.lastIndexOf(',');
                    int classCode = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(1 + lastComma));
                    int[] data = Arrays.stream(line.substring(0, lastComma).split(","))
                                       .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                                       .toArray();
                    ImageMatrix matrix = new ImageMatrix(data, classCode);
                    list.add(matrix);
                }
            }
            return this;
        }

        public void printResults(){
            for(ImageMatrix matrix: list){
                System.out.println(matrix);
            }
        }


        public Iterator<ImageMatrix> iterator() {
            return this.list.iterator();
        }
        public static void main(String[] args){
            ImageMatrixDB i = new ImageMatrixDB();
            try{
                i.load("cw2DataSet1.csv"); 
                i.printResults();
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Added your suggestions still recieving Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Unhandled exception type IOException

Comment: Check the answer, I have updated your code, including handling the exception. Because you throw IOException in your load() method, you must catch it in your main, where you call ImageMatrixDB.load().

Comment: Ahh I see where the issue was, Thanks for clearing it up will really help. Now onto trying to implement a kNN algorithm :) Thanks again.

Comment: one issue I see, the data set being outputted to the terminal is the same one repeated :/

Comment: Yea, I found it too, the ImageMatrix.data property was `static`. Well, there you go, a concrete example of why to avoid static variables unless absolutely necessary. I have updated the answer to correct the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your load method can throw an `IOException`. You need to catch it in order to successfully compile

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ImageMatrixDB i = new ImageMatrixDB();
    try{
        i.load("dataset1.csv"); // <<< ERROR IS HERE
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```